# How align some top main divi menu Items

Tags: css, wordpress, division

I am using divi theme with a menu at the top which is aligned center.now I want to align the last two items to the most right side of the bar.
How can I do it?
Thanks for any code or help on this.

Comment: What does this have to do with arithmetic division?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the :nth-child() pseudo class selector. Let's say your menu has code which is something like this:

```
<div class=menu>
<ul>
<li class=menu-item>Menu 1</li>
<li class=menu-item>Menu 2</li>
<li class=menu-item>Menu 3</li>
<li class=menu-item>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now let's say you want to move your 'Menu 3' and 'Menu 4' item to the right, you can target those elements and style them like so:

```
.menu-item:nth-child(3),.menu-item:nth-child(4) {float:right; /*or margin-left:50px;*/}
```

By that, only those menus will be targeted and styled. See my pen [here](https://codepen.io/ashishtadigiri/pen/BayKeJa)

Comment: That's perfect. now I can move them where I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad... Please don't forget to verify my answer. Thanks.